# Fatal Error to developp onAuthenticationFailure

Tags: symfony

I am implementing authentification with ajax and `FOSUserBundle` in symfony2. This is my code in security.yml :

```
 main:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                default_target_path: hello
                remember_me: true
                success_handler: my.success_handler
                failure_handler: my.success_handler
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            remember_me:
                key:        %secret%
            anonymous: false
            logout: true
```

and services.yml:

```
my.success_handler:
        class:   Kgr\UserBundle\Controller\SuccessHandler
        arguments: [@router]
```

and class SuccessHandler :

```
namespace Kgr\UserBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

class SuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
            $response = new Response(json_encode(array(
                'success'=> 1,
            )));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
        }else{
            if ($token->getUser()->isSuperAdmin()) {
                return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin'));
            }
            else {
                return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('MyAppmondeUserBundle_homepage'));
            }
        }
    }

     public  function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
            $response = new Response(json_encode(array(
                'success'=> 0,
            )));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
        }else{
            if ($token->getUser()->isSuperAdmin()) {
                return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin'));
            }
            else {
                return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('MyAppmondeUserBundle_homepage'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did not understand the error :

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Kgr\UserBundle\Controller\SuccessHandler::onAuthenticationFailure() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface::onAuthenticationFailure() in D:\wamp1\www\Symfony\src\Kgr\UserBundle\Controller\SuccessHandler.php on line 12
```

against the method by onAuthenticationSuccess walking alone

Answer (score 2):

You've missed use statement for `AuthenticationException`.

Add `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;` to the top

Comment: @dev_symfo could you mark question answered if everything is solved now